# Lucene scoring, precision about vector space model

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, similarity

I'm not sure to understand how vector space model is used in lucene scoring.

I read here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html) that lucene scores a document as the sum of the tf-idf of each term query (if we omit coordination factor, field length and boosts). I don't understand how vector space model is used.

Space vector model could be used to calculate the similarity between the tf-idf vector of a document and the tf-idf vector of the query.
This should give us a CosSimilarity score between the query and a document. The score would be between 0 and 1, so different requests should be easy to compare.

Why not using lucene score ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene uses the 'practical score function' mentioned in your link, which is an approximation of the cosine similarity - extended to support 'practical' features such as boosts.

If you take the vector space cosine similarity formula for a query q and a document d, you have:

```
s(q, d) = q * d / (||q|| * ||d||)
```

Considering that q and d are vectors like `[tf(t1) * idf(t1), ...]`, and that in the q vector tf(t) is either 1 or 0, the formula becomes:

```
s(q, d) = ∑( tf(t in d) * idf(t)² )(t in q) / (||q|| * ||d||)
```

You can further replace `||q||` with `1 / queryNorm(q)` given their definition `queryNorm = 1 / √sumOfSquaredWeights`

```
s(q, d) = queryNorm(q) * ∑( tf(t in d) * idf(t)² )(t in q) / ||d||
```

which is close to the formula they give in the docs:

```
score(q, d) = queryNorm(q) * coord(q,d) * 
              ∑ ( tf(t in d) * idf(t)² * t.getBoost() * norm(t,d)) (t in q)
```

`||d||`, the norm of the document vector, however, does not have a direct equivalent in the terms of their formula.

Comment: Ok that make sense, so `norm(d)` is defined as  `√numTerms(d)`  ?

Comment: No, it's not the same norm - I've cleaned up the notation in my answer. ||d|| does not have a direct equivalent term in their formula, but it might be included in coord(q,d).