# Usage of the practical scoring function and the vector space model in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

From the documentation of Elasticsearch, under the section ["Theory behind Relevance Scoring"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html), it is specified that the software uses [Lucene's practical scoring function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html), which computes the matching score of document *d* to search query *q* by taking into account the term-frequency and the inverse document frequency of terms in *d*, normalizing and weighting by the length of the document. The practical scoring function (psf) is meant to compute the relevance of multiterms queries.

Now, it also says it uses a vector space model to compute the similarity (using the cosine similarity) of a multiterms query to a document.

Question is: if the rank is computed through the psf, why the need of a similarity computation at all? Isn't the relevance score already meant to rank documents? 
How do the two things interact?

Comment: This is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046269/lucene-scoring-precision-about-vector-space-model